# apksigner returns back with nothing

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-studio-3.0, apksigner

as you can see from the title I am having difficulty getting apksigner to work. I have tried using the terminal in android studio and the command line however they both seem to return exactly the same; with nothing.

No matter what I type in I end up with the same [result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ME24C.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
//Go to the location of `apksigner.bat` file    
C:\Users\Administrator>cd C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\

C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3>apksigner --help
```

the `apksigner.bat` file may be in another folder which is different from the example.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used a very old version (v28) of Android build tools (which still used the java signer), in android studio I downloaded the newest version of android build tools and used the apksigner there. This solved the issue for me.

The following commands worked:

```
apksigner --help
```

and

```
apksigner sign --ks mykeystore-key.keystore --ks-pass pass:keystorePass --v1-signing-enabled true --v2-signing-enabled true zipalignedAPK.apk
```

This currently generates signs the apk in a way that can be uploaded to the play store.